# Rails: Created params not saving correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, select, model-view-controller

I'm practicing building a Rails application. I am trying to build an application that uses authors and books. The purpose of the app is to have a display page for Books, a display page for Authors, and some links that connect the two. I almost have it ready. My only issue is, whenever I try to save the name of the author, it is being saved as a link to the author's page.

Here is what I am starting with:
schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do

  create_table "books", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "author_id"
    t.string   "author_name"
    t.index ["title"], name: "index_books_on_title", unique: true
  end

  create_table "authors", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "bio"
  end

end
```

Here are my sample data in seeds.rb

```
books = [
  {title:"Ruby Programming", author_id: 1, author_name: "John Smith"},
{title:"Java Programming", author_id: 2 , author_name: "Jane Adams"},
{title:"PHP Programming", author_id: 3, author_name: "Mike Jones"},
{title:"Python Programming", author_id: 1, author_name: "John Smith"}
]

authors = [
  {name:"John Smith", bio: "John Smith loves Ruby and Python"},
  {name:"Jane Adams", bio: "Jane Adams loves Java"},
  {name:"Mike Jones", bio: "Mike Jones loves PHP"}
]
```

Here is my books_controller.rb

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @books = Books.all
    if params[:search]
      @books = Book.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @books = Book.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

  end

  def show
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @book = Book.new
  end

  def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)

    if(@book.save)
      redirect_to @book
    else
      render 'already_exists'
    end
  end

  private def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:id, :title, :author_id, :author_name)
  end

end
```

Here is my author_controller.rb

```
class AuthorsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @authors = Author.all
  end

  def show
    @author = Author.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

Here is my models/book.rb

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :author
    validates :title, presence:true, length: {minimum:1}
end
```

And here is my models/author.rb

```
class Superpower < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :books
end
```

So, I am trying to make it so that users can create a new book with one of the selected authors. After creating the book, they will be redirected back to a new page that will display the book's title and the author's name (which will link back to the the author's page with their bio).

Here is views/books/new.html.erb

```
<h1> Add Book </h1>

<%= form_for :book, url: books_path do |f| %>

    <p>
    <%= f.label :title %> <br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>

    <p>
    <%= f.label :author_id, "Author" %> <br>
    <%= collection_select(:book, :author_id, Author.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => 'Please select'}, class: 'form-control' ) %>
    </p>

    <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
    <p>
    <% end %>
```

Here is views/book/show.html.erb

```
<h2> Title: <%= @book.title %> </h2>

<h2> Author: <%= link_to @book.author_name, author_path(@book.author_id) %> </h2>

<p> <%= link_to "Go back to Books", root_path %> </p>
```

But instead of displaying this:

```
Title: Ruby Programming
Author: John Smith
```

I get this:

```
Title: Ruby Programming
Author: authors/1
```

I suspect that this has something to do with my form for selecting authors, but I don't know why the "author_name" isn't saving as the author_name string, but as the direct link to the author's page. This error is messing up other parts of my application and i've been puzzling over it for a few days now. Can anyone assist?

Comment: I think as you have has_one :author association in Book Model, so there is no need of additional field "author_name" attribute as when you create book by selecting any specific author id it will  get associated with author so you can make use of either @book.author.name or can make use of delegate in Book model. Instead of adding an extra attribute have you tried this approach

Answer (score 0):

You are not generating the right way the author_name field of the book, but you don't need it at all, if you have the relationship and the author table has a name field, you can always use book_instance.author.name, or you can generate in the book model a method author_name which returns this.

So, remove the author_name field from book table with a migration, remove it from strong params in controller, and add the next method to the book model:

```
def author_name
  self.author.name
end
```

This should work

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried this, but now all I am getting is:
Title: Ruby Programming
Author: 1

So now it's just displaying the ID.

Comment: Where are you getting that ?

Comment: OK, another thing, if you have the author_id in the book table, you must use belongs_to instead of has_one in book model...

Comment: Thanks, I finally got it to work thanks to your suggestions!

Comment: Or do `delegate :name, to: :author, prefix: true, allow_nil: true`

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can fix this:

```
before_create :set_author_name
```

OR

```
before_validation(on: :create) do
  set_author_name
end
```

And define the method as follows inside book model:

```
def set_author_name
  self.author_name = self.author.name
end
```

Another point, it should be `belongs_to :author` instead of `has_one :author` in your Book model.

Hope this helps.